# How to monitor JVM usages for Websphere Applications?

Tags: jvm, websphere, ibm-jdk, jstat, ibm-jvm

I'm trying to monitor JVM usages in IBM Websphere Server. Normally I use jstat tool from the JDK but since that's not available with IBM WAS, is there any other tool available for the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WAS uses IBM's J9 JVM under the hood. So, some of the HotSpot JVM's debugging tool will not work with it. WAS exposes all details using [Performance Monitoring Infrastucture(PMI)](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was/8.5.5?topic=organization-java-virtual-machine-counters). You should be able to get lots of metrics using it. You need to enable this feature in order to get metrics.